when $x^2+2$ splits $\operatorname{mod}p$
Why $x^2+2$ splits iff $p \equiv 1$ or $3 \bmod 8$.
It is easy to check $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8 \quad x^2+2$ splits. In fact, if $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains a 8 th root of 1. Then $\left(\xi-\xi^{-1}\right)^2+2=0$, so $x^2+2$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_p$. so $8 \mid p-1, p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$.
I am confused about another situation when $p \equiv 3 \bmod 8$.

$-2$ is a quadratic residue also when $p\equiv3\pmod8$

@J.W.Tanner I am confused about how to prove this

$2$ and $-1$ are not quadratic residues when $p\equiv3\pmod8$

@J.W.Tanner I see.But why are 2 and -1  not quadratic residues when  $p \equiv 3 \mathrm{mod} 8$?

@J.W.Tanner I have seen such conclusion in wiki.But there is no proof.

Quadratic reciprocity is proved in any book on elementary number theory, and also on this site. Have a look. $-1$ is a QR iff $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$ for an odd prime $p$. And $2$ is a quadratic nonresidue for $p\equiv \pm 3 \bmod 8$.

Cf. proof section in wikipedia

@DietrichBurde OK.Thank you.

One proof is given here, for example.

Also see proofs using quadratic Gauss sums in this Wikipedia article and also see here

I meant here

@J.W.Tanner OK.Thank you.

You are essentially asking if $-2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, where $p\equiv 3\pmod8$.  It is, because $-1$ and $2$ are not quadratic residues under that condition.  Proofs of the latter abound in number theory textbooks, on Wikipedia here and here, and on this site here and here.
